# Checking the shell method with the disc method.

Tags: calculus

The problem is: "Find the volume of rotation about the $x$-axis for $y=(x-3)^\frac{1}{3} - 2$ where $11 \leq x \leq 30$. When I used the shell method I obtained:

$$\int_{0}^1 2\pi y(16-(y+2)^2) \,dy = \frac{53 \pi}{6}$$

But when I used the disc method my integral turned out to be: $$\int_{11}^{30} \pi ((x-3)^{\frac{1}{3}}-2))^2 \,dx = \frac{38 \pi}{5}$$

Comment: How did you get $(y+2)^2$ in the first integral?  Basically it looks like you have the right idea for setting up the integrals, it seems to me as if this is just a careless error.

Answer (score 1):

I did a quick shell method solution and got $\frac{38\pi}{5}$.  I think your mistake is when determining the length *h* in the integral for shell method $V=2\pi\int_{c}^{d}{ph~dy}$.  This plot should help.
http://17trek.com/help-files/2014-03-07/plot-labeled.png

When I teach this I have my students draw these lengths and come up with the equation $x+h=30$ and solve for *h* giving $h=30-x$.  
So all you need to do is solve the equation $y=(x-3)^{1/3}-2$ for *x*, plug it in that equation for *h* and you are set.

Answer (score 0):

The shell approach is supposed to give:
$$\displaystyle\int_{0}^1 2\pi y(30) dy-\displaystyle\int_{0}^1 2\pi y(3+(y+2)^3) dy $$